# How to specify .gcno and .gcda directory separately in Gcov?

Tags: gcov

I'm going to have multiple `.gcda` files in my project. One for each test case. Because `gcov` will merge `.gcda` for each test case execution, I move each `.gcda` file to a different directory.

When calling `gcov`, I tried to specify `.gcda` (`.\data\gcda\evenodd.gcda`) and `.gcno` (`.\data\gcno\evenodd.gcno`) files.

I used `-o data\` but it seems that `gcov` doesn't scan the path subdirectories.

Then, I tried to specify each file's path like this:

`gcov -o data\gcno\evenodd.gcno data\gcda\evenodd.gcda evenodd.c`

because I thought it would accept more than one path. Alas, the result is :
[image: Result1]

By putting the `.gcda` path first instead of `.gcno`, this is what I got:
[image]

Since the default location of these files is in the source file directory, I tried to put `.gcno` there and then specify `.gcda` path. It didn't work.
[image]

Based on those results, `gcov` won't receive more than one path for `-o`.

Apparently `gcov` will always look for `.gcno` and `.gcda` in pair when `-o` is specified. Is there a way to do this other than putting both of them in the same directory?

Comment: "gcov will merge .gcda for each test case execution" - isn't this a _good thing_? You are normally interested in cumulative coverage of your testsuite, not coverage of individual tests.

Answer (score 0):

You should not move `.gcno`/`.gcda` files to different folder after generation because gcov will not be able to locate related source files. Moreover, gcov has to be run in exact same directory where test executable has been compiled.